# When using ngRoute, are controllers duplicated?

Tags: angularjs, memory, controller, routes

I'm using ngRoute, with the following configuration :

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/view1', {
      controller:'my1Ctrl',
      templateUrl:'views/view1.html'
    })
    .when('/view2', {
      controller:'my2Ctrl',
      templateUrl:'views/view2.html'
    });
}])
```

For the purpose of this example, I'm logging the ID of the controller every second. So, in the my1Ctrl controller, I add the following code :

```
$scope.f = function(){
    console.log('Test Controller, id: ', $scope.$id);
    setTimeout($scope.f, 1000);
};
setTimeout($scope.f, 1000);
```

Finally, I launch my app and navigate 3 times from view1 to view2. After that, every second, I get the following log:

```
Test Controller, id:  00A
Test Controller, id:  00I
Test Controller, id:  00E
```

If my test case is not relevant, please tell me.

**My question**: When ngRoute instanciates a new controller, is the old one removed or is it still in memory? If it is, can I configure ngRoute to re-use the same controller or to distroy the old one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.$id` is not the id of the controller but of the scope instead.

When you open new page defined with `$routeProvider` AngularJS "instantiates" new controller (i.e. calls the internal method `instantiate`). This method invokes the controller's function with `new` so it creates new object. But it's not all AngularJS does. Before calling the controller's constructor with `new`, AngularJS resolves all it's dependencies. If the controller has local dependency called `$scope` AngularJS creates new `$scope`, each scope has unique identifier - `$scope.$id`.

Of course, in order to prevent memory leaks AngularJS does not keep old controllers in the memory, so you shouldn't worry about this.

Comment: Oh! you're right, it's the scope id ^^ I'm thinking about it and come back soon to validate or adding questions. thanks

Comment: So, the  scope of the old controller is kept? Even if it's not linked with a controller anymore ?

Comment: No it is not, when you leave the page the `$scope` of the controller is garbage collected as well.

Comment: Well, so it's my setTimeout binding which is causing this effect. This test is not relevant. Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you keep reference to the `$scope` it is not being garbage collected, this is common cause of memory leaks.